# Android - Can't reload/refresh Fragment

Tags: android, fragment

Here is my code, inside specific Fragment

```
parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commit()
```

It not working, Fragment isn't reloaded. I'm using Navigation Component, Fragment v1.3.4, I want to reload Fragment after change locale language.

Thanks.

Comment: why you want to refresh the fragment, if you can please tell me that, maybe there is a better solution for you

Comment: I change app language, so I want to reload current fragment for display textview with new string.

Comment: Please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-app-language-programmatically-in-android